# Generate XML File using the LIST Data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I have the data in the list as below.

```
List<APIConfigValue>
```

Now I have to generate the XML file as below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ScanTime.Web" value="11D_SVC1" />
    <add key="eTime.Punch" value="true" />
    <add key="DataMartUrl" value="syscontrol" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Based on the no of records in the list, it should automatically generate.
I am trying using xml linq libraries.

This is how i started...

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("configuration",
                new XElement("appSettings",
                    new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", "APP.Web"), new XAttribute("value", "true"))
                    )
            )
        );
```

I got stuck on how to loop through from the list here. I tried to find articles. But nothing close.
Appreciate your time and Responses.

Comment: You should maybe use the XmlSerializer class instead of the XDocument.

Comment: How does *APIConfigValue* look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that each `APIConfigValue` has two properties: `key` and `value`.

```
List<APIConfigValue> data = foo;
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("configuration",
        new XElement("appSettings",
            data.Select((conf) => new XElement("add", new XAttribute("key", conf.key), new XAttribute("value", conf.value)).ToArray()
        )
    )
);
```

What this does is map each `APIConfigValue` to an `XElement` with two properties: the `key` and `value` of the `APIConfigValue`.

However, if you plan on both exporting and importing this XML format I would recommend taking a look at the [`XMLSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've populated your List accordingly:

```
List<APIConfigValue> yourList = //assign your list here;
foreach (APIConfigValue apiConfigItem in yourList)
{
    //write out your nodes from the list here using apiConfigItem
}
```